# What's the dimension of image set of linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider the linear map $ f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $ given by
$$ f(x)=Ax+b $$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $ b \in \mathbb{R}^m $ and $x$ can be any vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**What's the dimension of the set $f\left(\mathbb{R}^n \right)$?**

In linear algebra, the dimension means the minimum amount of linearly independent vectors needed to span the space in question. If I was considering only the map given by $g(x)=Ax$, then obviously $ \dim g(\mathbb{R}^n) =n$. But for $f \left(\mathbb{R}^n \right) $ I also need the vector $b$ to find all points in $f \left(\mathbb{R}^n \right) $. However I can't take any linear combination involving it, because then the vectors would span some bigger set.

Comment: Take the canonical basis $\mathcal C=\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n\subset \mathbb R^n$ and compute $f(e_i)$.  The linear independent columns of the matrix $M=(f(e_1)\vert\dots\vert f(e_n))$ span the image of $f$ (observe that $\forall i=1,\dots,n$, $f(e_i)\in\mathbb R^m$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b=0$, we don't always get $\dim f(\Bbb R^n)=n$ (especially if $m<n$).
Rather, the dimension of the image of a linear map is called its *rank*, which is the same as the rank of the matrix $A$: the maximum number of independent columns.

If $b\ne 0$, the image $f(\Bbb R^n)$ is in general not a linear subspace but an *affine subspace*, namely the column space of $A$ shifted by $b$.
As an affine subspace, its dimension is still ${\rm rank}(A)$.